How to grant full access to a single AWS Amplify app?
I'm trying to attach an IAM policy to a permission set so that I could grant different users through IAM Identity Center access to their own AWS Amplify apps. For some reason, the below policy doesn't show any of the branches that's deployed in the app but still lets them edit most of the configuration and settings.
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:ListApps"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "amplify:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:amplify:us-east-1:123455678:apps/abcdefg"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Tried also to grant all of the Amplify actions explicitly in the policy instead of the amplify:* but no luck so far. What am I missing?
